# flutter grid view showing some spacing

Tags: flutter

I am using Gridview in my app I need to line horizontal and vertical. So I change the background color to grey but the issue it's showing some extra space how can I remove it?

```
Container(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    child: GridView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                        crossAxisCount: 4,
                      ),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat1.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),
                              Text(
                                'Computer Hardware',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat2.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),

                              Text('Computer Software',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat3.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),


                              Text('Internet', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat4.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),

                              Text('Mobile / Table & iPad',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat5.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),

                              Text(
                                'Printer & Scanner',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat6.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),

                              Text('CCTV Cameras', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),

                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat7.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),

                              Text('Smart TV/Home Theater',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.01,),
                              Container(
                                height: Height * 0.04,
                                child: Image.asset('images/cat8.png'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: Height * 0.008,),

                              Text('E-Learning', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image]

You can see in the image its showing a grey color on top I need to remove this. I am not using any padding etc in container still its showing this

Comment: `GridView` has a `padding` property which has some default value. set it to `EdgeInsets.all(0)` explicitly and it should work as you intend to

Answer (score 0):

set gridview padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0)